# How to use variable for "TOP" in the sqlQuery of cosmos DB bindings?

Tags: javascript, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-durable-functions

I was creating a simple page using durable function which is triggered by http request, getting data from cosmos db, and use the result as http response.

I used JavaScript and followed the Azure official documents.

In the Orchestrator, I called `context.df.callActivity("Action1", {"top":10})`

In the "Action1"'s `function.json`, I added a cosmos DB binding with sqlQuery as `SELECT TOP {top} * FROM e`.

I got error message:

> The count value provided for a TOP clause must be an integer.

I've searched and tried using udf like `SELECT TOP udf.toInteger({top}) *...`
or built-in function like `SELECT TOP StringToNumber({top}) *...`
but none of them works.

So the question is how can I use a variable like "TOP x" in the sqlQuery for cosmos DB binding?

Comment: As far as I see, the conversion seems to do it for a `string` value https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB/CosmosDBSqlResolutionPolicy.cs#L49, if that is so, the issue is that the value is not an integer.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Thanks for looking it up. Does that mean there's no way?

Comment: Not that I can currently see. TOP requires an int, and there is no current way to tell the SqlParameter parser that you want an int, not a string, from the `{variable}` syntax, it just takes the name.

Comment: Could you please have a try with the code: context.df.callActivity("Action1", {top=10})

Comment: @HuryShen Just tried. Can't even load the function. The error message is `SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer`